# Numpy covariance matrix nonrmalisation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, covariance, normalize

I know that `numpy.cov` calculates the covariance given a N dimensional array.

I can see [from the documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1780) that the normalisation is done by `(N-1)`. But for my specific case, the covariance matrix is given by:

[image]

where `xi`  is the quantity. `i` and `j` are the bins.

As you can see from the above equation, this covariance matrix is normalised by `(N-1)/N`.

**TO GET THE ABOVE NORMALISATION**

***Can I simply multiply the covariance matrix obtained from `numpy.cov` by `(N-1)**2 / N` to get the above normalisation? Is that correct?***

***Or Should I use the `bias` parameter inside `numpy.cov`? If so how?***

Comment: With `bias=1`, normalisation is by `N`. Therefore, I believe you can just multiply the result by `N-1`?

Comment: @BeRecursive: So I call `np.cov` with `bias=1` and then multiply the result by `N-1` ? Isn't it the same as multiplying it by `(N-1)**2 / N` with `bias` set default??

Comment: Of course, but that's a lot more work to do :) I would also double check this by quickly implementing it naively yourself and checking that the result you get is what you expect. No harm in double checking!

Comment: @BeRecursive: yep I shall do that. But doing the above two methods, is it the correct procedure if we need a manual normalisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. We can call `np.cov` with `bias=1` and then multiply the result by `N-1`

or

2. We can multiply the overall covariance matrix obtained by `(N-1)**2/N`